# Function is solution of given ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been stuck on following question problem

> Q. Show that the indicated family of function is a solution of the given ODE
>
> **i)**$$y=2xy'+y(y')^2\qquad; \qquad y^2=C\left(x+\frac{C}{4}\right)$$
> **ii)**$$x^3y'''+2x^2y''-xy'+y=12x^2\qquad ; \qquad y=C_1x+C_2x\ln{x}+4x^2$$
> **iii)**$$y=xy'+\sqrt{1+(y')^2}\qquad; \qquad y=Cx+\sqrt{1+C^2}$$

Just needed little help I am not be able to find solution as these equations are non-linear after many attempts of trying m curious are even solution to these ODE's are possible or not.

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting. Is my edit correct?

Comment: You simply need to find the required derivatives, substitute into the given ODEs and show that LHS=RHS.

Comment: Just substitute into the ODEs

Comment: In i) substitute $u=y^2$, then i) and iii) are Clairaut ODE $y=xy'+f(y')$ that indeed have a solution family of lines of the indicated form $y'=C$, $y=Cx+f(C)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of solving the ODE's, it suffices to show that the left hand side and right hand side of the ODE's are equivalent. For example, let's take the second example **(ii)**:
$$x^3y'''+2x^2y''-xy'+y=12x^2 \tag{1}$$
The proposed solution is:
$$y=C_1 x+C_2 x \ln{x}+4x^2 \tag{2}$$
Thus, evaluating derivatives of $(2)$:
$$y'=C_2\cdot (\ln(x)+1)+C_1+8x$$
$$y''=\frac{C_2}{x}+8$$
$$y'''=-\frac{C_2}{x^2}$$
Substituting into $(1)$ gives:
$$x^3\left(-\frac{C_2}{x^2}\right)+2x^2\left(\frac{C_2}{x}+8\right)-x(C_2\cdot (\ln(x)+1)+C_1+8x)+(C_1 x+C_2 x \ln{x}+4x^2)=12x^2$$
The left hand side should have terms which cancel out nicely, and should turn out to be $12x^2$, which shows that $(2)$ is a solution to the ODE.